# How to generate multiple pdf's using html-pdf-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I need to create html to pdf for multiple contents and for that I am using [**html-pdf-node**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-node). Here is my code

```
let files = [
  { url: "<h1>Welcome to html-pdf-node</h1>", name: 'example.pdf' }, 
  { url: "<h1>Welcome to html-pdf-node</h1>", name: 'example.pdf' }
]
let options = { format: 'A4', path: 'mypdffile.pdf' };

const d = await htmlToPdf.generatePdfs(files, options)
```

It creates the pdf but only single file with the name `mypdffile.pdf`. But I need all the pdf inside a folder. I am not able to find the way. Pls help

Comment: I do not know that code but it looks like you tell it to write to the same file every time

Comment: the `path` key in the options takes the output's pdf file name. Where I can write the code for multiple `path`s?

Answer (score -2):

If you are not comfortable with this package try this

html-pdf -  https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

or else try renaming the file name in loops

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31144009)